# How to use jQuery to switch between a plus and minus sign on collapse and expand?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I am using the code below. What I want to do is have a **+** or **-** sign on expanded or collapsed view. How can I do that? Here is the code:

```
<!--//---------------------------------+
//  Developed by Roshan Bhattarai  |
//  http://roshanbh.com.np         |
//  Fell Free to use this script   |
//---------------------------------+-->
<title>Collapsible Message Panels</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
    $(".msg_body").show();
    //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
    $(".msg_head").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 570px;
    font: 75%/120% Verdana,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p {
    padding: 0 0 1em;
}
.msg_list {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 383px;
}
.msg_head {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background-color:#FFCCCC;
    margin:1px;
}
.msg_body {
    padding: 5px 10px 15px;
    background-color:#F4F4F8;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
  <p>Click on the each news head to toggle
</p>

</div>
<div class="msg_list">
        <p class="msg_head">Header-1 </p>
        <div class="msg_body">
            orem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>

        <p class="msg_head">Header-2</p>
        <div class="msg_body">
            consectetuer adipiscing elit orem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change the markup of the `msg_head` to something like this-

```
<p class="msg_head">Header-1 <span>[-]</span></p>
```

and change the toggle function to look like this-

```
$(".msg_head").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
})
.toggle( function() {
    $(this).children("span").text("[+]");
}, function() {
    $(this).children("span").text("[-]");
});
```

Comment: I just wanted to note that I have something exactly similar to this, but I have my click div using an href link.  If I put the span tag within the <a href> tag, it won't work.

I made a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/xBxa4/5/

I am pretty sure there is a way to make it work with the href links, but I just wanted to share since I was pulling my hair out wondering why it wasn't working for me.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to do this is with the [`.toggleClass( className )`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). Using this method you can add or remove a class from an element. So modifying your code to the (untested) code below should do the trick. You'll want to offset the padding by an equivalent amount to fit your graphic files.

**JavaScript**

```
$(".msg_head").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('msg_head_expanded');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.msg_head
{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  background:#FFCCCC url('plus.png') no-repeat 0 50;
  margin:1px;
}

.msg_head_expanded
{
   background:#FFCCCC url('minus.png') no-repeat 0 50;
}
```

Comment: You need your `.toggleClass` to be applied to `$(this)` not the `.msg_head` outside of the click function. And it needs `$('.msg_body').hide();`

Comment: @fudgey I thought that .slideToggle accomplished the hiding for you. I've pulled the .toggleClass inside of the event but I thought daisy chaining it onto the `.click` was cool. To be totally honest I know enough jQuery to be dangerous. So this is a good learning opportunity for me as I don’t claim to be an expert, just a curious professional looking to improve. ;-)

Comment: Actually it does do what you think, but having it outside of the click function make it add the `msg_head_expanded` class while the message was hidden. And after clicking on the head, the toggleClass didn't get called again, so the `msg_head_expanded` class was always there. Anyway, I gave you +1 because this is how I would do this now :)

Comment: @fudgey now I understand what you were saying. Thanks for the feedback. Corrections are what happen when I post code extemporaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I have this very thing on my own website. Here's how I do it:

```
$(".question").click(function () {
    if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next(".answer").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('-');
    } else {
        $(this).next(".answer").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children('span').text('+');
    }
});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="question">
    <span>+</span>blahblah
</div>
<div class="answer">blahblah</div>
```